# spring ws soap client+jaxb2

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services, jaxb

I am using the JAXb2 maven plugin to create the domain[bean ]classes.

When i try to hit the service thru WebServiceTemplate class, I am getting below error.

```
Exception:org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://services.abc.cde.efg.com", local:"xxxLookupResponse"). Expected elements are <{services.abc.cde.efg.com"}xxxLookupRequest>,<{services.abc.cde.efg.com"}xxxLookupResponse>,<{services.abc.cde.efg.com"}zzzUploadOrder>
```

and my bindings file looks as follows.

I am wondering how is it expecting three elements, that too the last one is not at all related with this webservice and not defined in jaxb binding file also. I have checked the created bean classes and they are not interrelated.

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="abcsServices.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='xxxxxLookupRequest']">
            <annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement"
                    name="xxxxxxLookupRequest" />
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="abcsServices.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='xxxxxLookupResponse']">
            <annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement"
                    name="xxxxxLookupResponse" />
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

Please throw some light on this. I am stuck here.

Client code:

```
ObjectFactory objFactory = new ObjectFactory(); xxxxLookupRequest req = objFactory.createxxxxLookupRequest(); req.setxxxx("12344"); req.setxxxxx("34234"); xxxxxLookupResponse response = (xxxxxLookupResponse) xxxxClient .doDeliveryLookUp(req);
```

========

spring client code:

```
response = (xxxxxLookupResponse) getWebServiceTemplate() .marshalSendAndReceive(xxxxLookupRequest, new SoapActionCallback("urn:xxxxxLookup"));
```

Comment: please provide a SOAP message which causes this exception

Comment: I do not have a direct xml request. But I am trying to set the values thru the bean classes and hit the webservices.

Comment: could you then show a piece of code which populates the message beans?

Comment: please add this as a formatted code to the question body to improve readability

Comment: @SergeyPauk - Yeah i have moved the code to question body. Thanks

Comment: Hi, can anyone help. I am stuck here. Not sure, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How do you create your JAXBContext? Please show the Spring configuration.

The error message is also weird:

`...unexpected element (uri:"http://services.abc.cde.efg.com", local:"xxxLookupResponse"). Expected elements are ... <{services.abc.cde.efg.com"}xxxxxLookupResponse>...`

Do you have matching names (`xxxLookupResponse` vs. `xxxxxLookupResponse`) here?

My theory is that you have one package (`services.abc.cde.efg.com`) generated or defined in two places and JAXB is picking the wrong one.

The binding files you refer to are not directly considered by JAXB, they are only used during the code generation. JAXB works with the generated classes then.

Comment: actually xxxLookupResponse vs. xxxxxLookupResponse refers to same bean. I updated my question. The issue here is it is looking for additional elements. Not able to figure out this.

Comment: @user3684106 You still don't show how you create your `JAXBContext`.

Comment: I am trying to follow this example. https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/